# How to store images in an SQL database on WP7

Tags: c#, database, image, windows-phone-7

I'm desperately trying to save an image to an SQL database and then load it on my WP. All of the guides online say to convert the image to a Byte array, store it and then load it back into an image.

So far, I've been able to save the image into a Byte array using:

```
    public static byte[] ConvertToBytes(Stream photoStream)   
    {   
        byte[] a = new Byte[photoStream.Length];   
        for (int i = 0; i < photoStream.Length; i++)   
        {   
            a[i] = (Byte)photoStream.ReadByte();   
        }   
        return (a);
    }
```

This generates a Byte array that is similar in size to the image I'm saving.

The suggested way to load images is:

```
    1 public static BitmapImage ConvertToImage(Byte[] inputBytes)   
    2 {   
    3     MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(inputBytes);   
    4     BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();   
    5     image.SetSource(stream);   
    6     return (image);   
    7 }
```

This doesn't work.

I get this error (on line 5):
"Unspecified error"

Does anybody have any idea how to fix this or can suggest an alternative method/code?

I know there is information online - i can assure you that i have searched long and hard for a working method and been able to make nothing work.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please show how you are getting inputbytes from the database.

Comment: try this link http://www.redmondpie.com/inserting-in-and-retrieving-image-from-sql-server-database-using-c/ i am sure that it can help

Comment: For testing purposes, I'm not even using the database. I convert an image to bytes and then send those bytes into ConvertToImage. I'm looking at your link now DJ KRAZE

Comment: @DJKRAZE: this example uses System.Drawing, which is not supported in WP7.

Comment: @CameronFisher: so your main problem now is how to display the image?

Comment: if he were to save the images to a location and a name such a something.jpg it would work I believe correct me if I am wrong GertArnold

Comment: That's exactly my problem - regular c# is fine, it's just in WP7 I have my problem. Basically, the user picks a picure from the pictures hub - it then needs to be stored in the database and then retrieved at a later date and displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this using:

```
public static byte[] ConvertToBytes(String imageLocation)
    {
        StreamResourceInfo sri = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(imageLocation, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        BinaryReader binary = new BinaryReader(sri.Stream);

        byte[] imgByteArray = binary.ReadBytes((int)(sri.Stream.Length));

        binary.Close();
        binary.Dispose();
        return imgByteArray;
    }

    public static WriteableBitmap ConvertToImage(Byte[] inputBytes)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(inputBytes);
        WriteableBitmap img = new WriteableBitmap(400, 400);

        img.LoadJpeg(ms);

        return (img);
    }
```

Thanks for all your help guys.

Answer (score -1):

i used that code

```
  byte[] Arr = Convert.FromBase64String(Im); >> i think you need that steep 
 Stream memStream = new MemoryStream(Arr);

                                    WriteableBitmap wbimg = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(memStream);

                                    image2.Source = wbimg;
                                    image2.Tag = IlbumID;
```

if that nat work

try

```
memStream.Read (Arr ,0, Arr.Length );
```

Comment: im is a value from SQL database

Comment: Thank you, but I get "COMException was unhandled"... "Unspecified error". "memStream.Read (Arr ,0, Arr.Length );" returns an integer?